# How To Add Properties To New Object That You're Instantiating?

Tags: c#

```
var par = new Paragraph(new Run(""));
par.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
ThicknessConverter converter = new ThicknessConverter();
par.BorderThickness = (Thickness)converter.ConvertFromString("0.02cm");
```

I'm trying to later change "par" to have different text in it, but I don't know how to do it without resetting the properties:

```
par = new Paragraph(new Run("new text"));
```

Is there either a way to combine the lines setting the border brush and thickness with the instantiation of par, or just to change the text in the run?

Answer (score 2):

What you would want to do is create, and assign a variable, as the `Run();` object. `Run` has a `text` property that you can change.

```
var run = new Run("");
var par = new Paragraph(new Run(""));
par.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
ThicknessConverter converter = new ThicknessConverter();
par.BorderThickness = (Thickness)converter.ConvertFromString("0.02cm");
run.Text = string.Empty; //Your code here
```

Changing the Run object should change what the variable `par` has.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something like

```
var par = new Paragraph(new Run("")){BorderBrush= Brushes.Black, etc.};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it will be working on references why don't you just create a string:

string text = "";

use that instead and then you can change it programmatically or through a text box or something.

Comment: How does that change the paragraph object

Comment: If you save the text you would like displayed to a string the paragraph object just holds a reference to that string so if it changes the paragraph text will also change :) I hope that helps

Comment: What's the syntax for that sorry